# HTML5 video timeupdate event not triggering while focused on other tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

i have created one html5 video player with custom control.

```
<video id="ppVideo" ref={this.setVideoRef} webkit-playsinline>
     <source src="some url here" type="video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and i have added one `timeupdate` event listner on it.

```
document.getElementById("ppVideo").addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
 conole.log('it is trigerring now');
});
```

It's working fine when the particular tab is active. if i moved to other tab, video stopped playing and the `timeupdate` event stop triggering. in firefox same thing working fine on tab change.

I have checked other html video on other website. it's working fine in chrome on switching tab. is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: Does your video have sound?

Comment: @Kaiido Nope, the video don't have sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other videos probably have sound.

Chrome will pause automatically any muted video that is not in screen anymore (yes, just scrolling out of screen will do the same).

However, they keep playing the ones with sound:

```js
muted.ontimeupdate = e => {
  _muted_log.textContent = muted.currentTime;
}
talking.ontimeupdate = e => {
  _talking_log.textContent = talking.currentTime;
}

talking.volume = 0;
```

```css
.log{
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
body{
  height: 9000px;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted id="muted" loop src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm"></video>

<video autoplay id="talking" loop src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm"></video>

<div class="log">
muted: <pre id="_muted_log"></pre>
talking: <pre id="_talking_log"></pre>
</div>
```

So if you wish yours to be playing even when hidden, add a sound track to it, but note that you will then need an user-interaction on your page before being able to autoplay it.

Comment: can we programatically add sound track to muted video ??